# Registration form will not submit data to database if I use action attribute to open a confirmation page

Tags: php, html, forms, action

My code will submit data to my database if I use **action=""**, but I want the action attribute to open a confirmation page to let users know their data has been registered. This confirmation page should appear onclick of the submit button and only after user's data has been stored in my database.  My code will not submit data to my database if I use **action="regconfirm.html"** (which is my confirmation page), but the confirmation page opens like it should.  I have tried to use **onsubmit="location.href='...registerform/regconfirm.html'"** and **onclick="location.href='...registerform/regconfirm.html'"** in the submit tag.  This also doesn't submit data to my database.  The form has many text fields and radio buttons which all work perfectly and validation is done using the **required** attribute in each field object's tag.  I believe the problem is in the form tag I am providing all code in the body here.

```
<body>

**<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">**
  <table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="497" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">(สามารถถ่ายเอกสารได้)</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" align="right"><table width="344" border="4" align="right" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="tableborder">
      <tr>
        <td width="306" colspan="2" align="right"><table width="326" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
          <tr>
            <td align="right">ใบเสร็จรับเงินเลขท
              <input name="text_1" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_1" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_1']; ?>" size="25" maxlength="255"  autofocus required/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">ลงวันท
              <input name="text_2" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_2" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_2']; ?>" size="25" maxlength="255"  required/></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">จำนวนเงิน
              <input name="text_3" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_3" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_3']; ?>" size="25" maxlength="255" required/></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="33" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="102" colspan="5" align="right"><img src="images/heading.jpg" alt="heading" width="731" height="96" align="absbottom" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="87" align="left"><strong>ท่านเป็น</strong></td>
    <td colspan="4" align="right">


      <input         name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" id="radio_1" value="Medicine"   required/>
      แพทย์
      <input         name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" id="radio_2" value="Nurse"   required/>
      พยาบาล
      <input         name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" id="radio_3" value="Academic"  required/>
      นักวิชาการ
      <input         name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" id="radio_4" value="Other"  required/>
      อื่นๆ


      <input name="text_4" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_4" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_4']; ?>" size="49" maxlength="255" required/></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="84">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left">ชื่อ..(โปรดระบุคำนำหน้า)</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><input name="text_5" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_5" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_5']; ?>" size="84" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">โรงพยาบาล
    <input name="text_6" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_6" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_6']; ?>" size="40" maxlength="255" required/></td>
    <td colspan="5" align="right">แผนก/หน่วย/ภาควิชา
    <input name="text_7" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_7" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_7']; ?>" size="29" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="70">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="266">เลขใบประกอบวิชาชีพ  (แพทย์ / พยาบาล)</td>
    <td width="417" align="right"><input name="text_8" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_8" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_8']; ?>" size="71" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="169">เลขที่สมาชิกสภาพยาบาล</td>
    <td width="514" colspan="7" align="right"><input name="text_9" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_9" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_9']; ?>" size="87" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="99">ที่อยู่ที่ติดต่อได้</td>
    <td width="612" colspan="8" align="right"><input name="text_10" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_10" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_10']; ?>" size="98" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="41">มือถือ</td>
    <td width="642" align="right"><input name="text_11" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_11" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_11']; ?>" size="108" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="295">โทรศัพท์
    <input name="text_12" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_12" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_12']; ?>" size="35" maxlength="255" required/></td>
    <td width="388" align="right">โทรสาร
    <input name="text_13" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_13" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_13']; ?>" size="53" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="42">E-mail: </td>
    <td width="641" align="right"><input name="text_14" type="email" class="formfield" id="email" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_14']; ?>" size="108" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="290">หากสนับสนุนโดยบริษัท  (โปรดระบุ) ชื่อผู้แทน</td>
    <td width="393" align="right"><input name="text_15" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_15" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_15']; ?>" size="66" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="52">โทรศัพท์</td>
    <td width="631" align="right"><input name="text_16" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_16" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_16']; ?>" size="105" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="123"><strong><u>รับประเภทอาหาร</u></strong></td>
    <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="51">

    <input  name="RadioGroup1" type="radio" id="radio_5" value="Thailand" required/>
ไทย</td>
    <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="76">

    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Vegetarian" id="radio_6" required/>
มังสวิรัติ</td>
    <td width="101">

    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Islam" id="radio_7" required/>
    อิสลาม</td>
    <td width="216">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="4" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blueborder_two">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="692">
      <tr>
        <td width="347" valign="top"><p align="center"><strong>อัตราค่าลงทะเบียน    (บาท)</strong></p></td>
        <td width="95" valign="top"><p align="center"><strong><u>ก่อน</u></strong><strong>  </strong><br />
          <strong>15  มี.ค.57</strong></p></td>
        <td width="104" valign="top"><p align="center"><strong><u>ตั้งแต่</u></strong><strong> </strong><strong> </strong><br />
          <strong>15    มี.ค.57</strong></p></td>
        <td width="95" valign="top"><p align="center"><strong><u>หน้างาน</u></strong></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="692">
      <tr>
        <td height="37" colspan="4" valign="middle"><span class="numbertext"><strong><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" />1</strong></span><strong>. <span class="numbertext">Pre-congress workshops</span>    (เลือกได้ 1 หัวข้อเท่านั้น)</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td width="341" height="15" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup3" value="1" id="RadioGroup3_0" required/>
          <strong>1</strong></td>
        <td width="93" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup4" value="2000" id="RadioGroup4_0" required/>
          2000</td>
        <td width="95" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup4" value="2300" id="RadioGroup4_1" required/>
          2300</label></td>
        <td width="77"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup4" value="2800" id="RadioGroup4_2" required/>
          <span class="numbertext">2800</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td height="40" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup3" value="2 " id="RadioGroup3_1" required/>
          <strong>2
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup3" value="3" id="RadioGroup3_2" required/>
              <strong>3</strong></label>
            <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup3" value="4" id="RadioGroup3_3" required/>
            <strong>4</strong></strong></td>
        <td width="93" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup5" value="1000" id="RadioGroup5_0" required/>
          1000</td>
        <td width="95" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup5" value="1300" id="RadioGroup5_1" required/>
          1300</td>
        <td width="77" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup5" value="1800" id="RadioGroup5_2" required/>
          1800</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="692">
      <tr>
        <td height="37" colspan="4" valign="middle"><strong> <span class="numbertext"><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" />2</span>. ประชุมวิชาการ  <span class="numbertext">(Main Congress) </span></strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td width="341" height="30"><strong> <img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" /><img src="images/bullet.jpg" width="8" height="8" alt="bullet" /> เป็นสมาชิกสมาคมเวชศาสตร์มารดาฯเลขที่......</strong></td>
        <td width="93" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup6" value="1700" id="RadioGroup6_0" required/>
          1700</td>
        <td width="96" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup6" value="2000" id="RadioGroup6_1" required/>
          2000</label></td>
        <td width="76" class="numbertext"><strong>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup6" value="2500" id="RadioGroup6_2" required/>
        </strong>2500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td height="30"><strong><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" /><img src="images/bullet.jpg" width="8" height="8" alt="bullet" /></strong><strong>ไม่ได้เป็นสมาชิกสมาคมเวชศาสตร์มารดาฯ</strong><strong> </strong></td>
        <td width="93" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup7" value="2200" id="RadioGroup7_0" required/>
          2200</label></td>
        <td width="96" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup7" value="2500" id="RadioGroup7_1" required/>
          2500</label></td>
        <td width="76" class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup7" value="3000" id="RadioGroup7_2" required/>
          3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr valign="middle">
        <td height="30"><strong><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" /><img src="images/bullet.jpg" width="8" height="8" alt="bullet" /> สำหรับ  Resident  / Fellow</strong></td>
        <td class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup8" value="800" id="RadioGroup8_0" required/>
          800</td>
        <td class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup8" value="1000" id="RadioGroup8_1" required/>
          1000</td>
        <td class="numbertext"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup8" value="1500" id="RadioGroup8_2" required/>
          1500</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="692">
      <tr>
        <td height="37" colspan="5" valign="middle"><span class="numbertext"><strong><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" />3</strong></span><strong>. </strong><strong>สมัครสมาชิกสมาคมฯ  ตลอดชีพ</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="250" height="50" valign="top" class="numbertext"><em class="bluetext"><img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" />(ดาวน์โหลดใบสมัครสมาชิกสมาคมฯ  และส่ง<img src="images/space.jpg" width="6" height="9" alt="space" />มาพร้อมกับใบลงทะเบียนประชุม)</em></td>
        <td width="80" valign="top" class="numbertext">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="90"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup9" value="800 " id="RadioGroup9_0" required/>
          <span class="numbertext">800</span></label>
          <br />
          </td>
        <td width="95" class="numbertext"><label>
          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup9" value="800 " id="RadioGroup9_1" required/>
          800</label>
          <br />
          </td>
        <td width="71"><span class="numbertext">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup9" value="800" id="RadioGroup9_2" required/>
            800</label>
          <br />
          <strong></strong></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><table width="692" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>





<?php      
      $sql = 'UPDATE regform SET `total` = `radio_12` + `radio_15` + `radio_18` + `radio_21` +`radio_24` + `radio_27`';
?> 





        <td height="46" align="right"><strong>รวมค่าลงทะเบียน  ข้อ <span class="numbertext">1+2+3</span>
          <input name="text_17" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_17" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['total']; ?>" maxlength="255" required/>
          <em><strong>บาท</strong></em></strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ต้องการให้ออกใบเสร็จในนาม  (ระบุ) </td>
    <td align="right"><input name="text_18" type="text" class="formfield" id="text_18" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['text_18']; ?>" size="76" maxlength="255" required/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="729" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="63">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong class="yellowhighlight"><u>การชำระเงิน</u></strong>  <u> เมื่อสมาคมฯได้รับชำระเงินแล้วเท่านั้น  จึงถือว่าการลงทะเบียนสมบูรณ์ </u></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="26" valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="RadioGroup10" value="Bank Transfer" id="RadioGroup10_0" required/>
      <span class="paymenttext">Bank Transfer</span></td>
    <td colspan="2">โอนเข้าบัญชี     &ldquo; <u>วิชาการสมาคมเวชศาสตร์มารดาและทารกในครรภ์ (ไทย)&rdquo;</u>      ธนาคารกรุงไทย บัญชีออมทรัพย์   <br />
    เลขที่  <u>041-0-08598-7</u>   สาขา <u>ถนนเพชรบุรีตัดใหม่</u></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="RadioGroup10" value="Money Order" id="RadioGroup10_1" required/>
      <span class="paymenttext">Money Order</span></td>
    <td colspan="2"><label>ธนาณัติสั่งจ่าย</label>
  <u>ปณ. เพชรบุรีตัดใหม่ </u><u>10311</u>    ในนาม <u>ศ.นพ.เยื้อน   ตันนิรันดร</u>  และส่งธนาณัติตัวจริงพร้อมใบลงทะเบียน  <br />
มายังสมาคมฯ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="RadioGroup10" value="Cheque" id="RadioGroup10_2" required/>
      <span class="paymenttext">Cheque</span></td>
    <td colspan="2"> เช็คสั่งจ่าย(เช็คต่างจังหวัดเพิ่มค่าธรรมเนียม  30 บาท) บัญชี<u>วิชาการสมาคมเวชศาสตร์มารดาและทารกในครรภ์</u><u>(ไทย)</u></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="RadioGroup10" value="Cash" id="RadioGroup10_3" required/>
      <span class="paymenttext">Cash</span></td>
    <td width="579"><label>เงินสด</label>
ณ สำนักงานสมาคมฯ<br />
<span class="bluetext">กรุณาส่งหลักฐานการชำระเงินพร้อมกับใบสมัครลงทะเบียนประชุมวิชาการ  มายังสมาคมฯ โทรสาร :   02-7181488   หรือทาง<br />
E-mail : <a href="mailto:mfm_th@yahoo.com">mfm_th@yahoo.com</a>,  por.boon@hotmail.com </span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top"><span class="redtext"><strong class="yellowhighlight"><em><u>หมายเหตุ</u></em></strong>     </span>
      <ol>
        <li class="redtext">ลงทะเบียน  Workshop ต้องลงทะเบียนประชุมวิชาการด้วย  และเลือกได้ 1  Workshop  เท่านั้น     </li>
        <li class="redtext">ผู้สมัครเข้าเป็นสมาชิกใหม่ สามารถลงทะเบียนใช้อัตราสมาชิกได้เลย</li>
        <li class="redtext">ผู้ลงทะเบียนหน้างาน อาจไม่ได้รับความสะดวก  กระเป๋าและเอกสารประกอบการประชุมอาจไม่ครบถ้วน </li>
        <li class="redtext"><strong><u>การยกเลิกการลงทะเบียน</u></strong> ผู้ที่ยกเลิกการลงทะเบียนจะต้องส่งหนังสือขอยกเลิกลงทะเบียนเป็นลายลักษณ์อักษรมายังสมาคมฯ  โดยจะได้รับคืนค่าลงทะเบียนภายหลังเสร็จสิ้นงานดังนี้  </li>
      </ol>
      <p><span class="redtext">ก่อนวันที่  10 เมษายน 2557 คืนร้อยละ 50 ของค่าลงทะเบียน     <br />
        หลังวันที่  10 เมษายน 2557 ไม่คืนค่าลงทะเบียน</span><br />
        <strong>  </strong><strong><em><u> </u></em></strong><br />
        <strong><u>ส่งใบลงทะเบียน,  ชำระค่าลงทะเบียน และสอบถามเพิ่มเติมได้ที่</u></strong><strong><u> </u></strong><br />
        คุณพรธวัล   บุญชนะทองเลิศ   <br />
        สมาคมเวชศาสตร์มารดาและทารกในครรภ์ (ไทย) <br />
        อาคารเฉลิมพระบารมี ๕๐ ปี ชั้น 8  เลขที่ 2  ซอยศูนย์วิจัย  ถ.เพชรบุรีตัดใหม่   <br />
        แขวงบางกะปิ  เขตห้วยขวาง   กรุงเทพฯ  10310<br />
        โทร. 02-7181489     มือถือ  087-6957659      โทรสาร. 02-7181488   <br />
        E-mail :  <a href="mailto:por.boon@hotmail.com">por.boon@hotmail.com</a>  หรือ  <a href="mailto:mfm_th@yahoo.com">mfm_th@yahoo.com</a> <br />
    Website :  <a href="http://www.thai-smfm.com">www.thai-smfm.com</a></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="images/bottomtext.jpg" width="728" height="359" alt="bottomimage" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"><strong class="bottomtext">ดาวน์โหลดแบบฟอร์มจองที่พักได้ที่  www.thai-smfm.com</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Click Here to Register Now"  onclick="location.href='http://localhost/registerform/regconfirm.html'"/>


  </tr>
</table></td>
      <td width="83"><p>



<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">

<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form" />


  </p>
</form>
<
```

/body>

Comment: Please show us some code you tried because we cant help you like this

Comment: "I believe the problem is in the code I am providing here."

You have some things messed up here. When you submit data you submit it to a php script not an html page which does not container server side code to handle the submit. Also if you want a poup, before / after the submit and database insertion you should look into AJAX using javascript (Assumming you dont want a page refresh).

Comment: Please list your exact requirement and list some code to help you. If you need the user registration script here is the link for you http://sysaxiom.com/php/user_login.php

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a html page with php when your code is done with writing to the database. The action tag should direct to the php file where your code handles the form data.

I hope i explained well.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Send the form to action= "".
Once the data is saved in database, redirect the form to confirmation page through php.

Syntax for redirect in php :

```
header('Location:http://yourdomain.com/registerform/regconfirm.html');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "regconfirm.html" create a "regconfirm.php"
Perform your database operation here.
once done regconfirm.php will show confirmation text.

example of form submit would be

< form action ="regconfirm.php" >

// Your Form Here

</form >